# example code for simple shared element transition android

Tags: android

After hours of trying I still struggle to buid a shared element transition with "changeBounds" in Android where the element that is moving is not the button that is clicked. In MainActivity.java this is the code that I tried so far:

```
public void onButtonNextClick(View v) {
    v.setTransitionName("transition1");
    ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, v, v.getTransitionName());
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Bnext) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i, optionsCompat.toBundle());
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help. I guess it's only a few lines that need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is this:

You're telling Android to set the Button as your `SharedElement`.

```
v.setTransitionName("transition1");
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat=ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, v, v.getTransitionName());
```

You're setting the transition on `v` which is your `Button`.

What you need to do:

Let's say you want to animate an ImageView, you can do the following:

```
public void onButtonNextClick(View view) {
    View imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            imageView.setTransitionName(“<your-transition-name>”);
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imageView, imageView.getTransitionName());
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }
        else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, helped a lot :). Apparently my votes do not count yet, sry for that.

Comment: hey no worries. glad it helped.